# Portrait images flip horizontal when uploaded

Tags: javascript, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, image-uploading

I have an MVC bootstrap page and when I select portrait photos they flip horizontal, I am using bootstrap file input.

```
<div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                        <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                            <img src="/Content/images/noimage.gif" alt="No Image">
                            <!--<img data-src="holder.js/100%x100%" alt="...">-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px;">

                            <img src="/content/postimages/medium/" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="existingFile-00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" value="1" />

                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Select image</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name="file0"></span>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

To try the page and see the files flip horizontal, please select a portrait image to upload on this page: http://allthings.trade/poultry/incubators/newpost

Comment: What type of device(s) are you uploading from? I've seen something similar when my wife sends me photos from her iPhone. On my Mac they're portrait as expected, but on my Windows machine they're flipped.

Comment: I have done some more reading and I have found the cause is I took the photo with an iPhone, then copied the photo to my pc and uploaded it from my PC. This shouldn't be a problem but apparently it is. If I upload directly from my iPhone it is fine, or if I open the photo and save it on the PC it is also fine. There are a few post about EXIF info that contributes to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I picked a portrait image and its displaying find, if I try to submit the form i am redirected to register page so I cant check it.
anyway this kind of problem is 90% from your backend it has nothing to do with bootstrap or your js most of the time.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have done some more testing and what I found is if I take a portrate photo with my iphone and upload that jpg, it will flip siteways. If i first open the image in MS paint, reduce the images by 10%, save it and upload it the image will not flip side ways. Any ideas?

Comment: yes check your backend, how do you handle to photo on the server?